# Does "adults aged X–Y" include people born between Y and Y+1 years ago?

Tags: meaning, terminology

Sometimes people use age ranges to define groups of people, like "young adults are defined as people aged 18—30". To me that sounds ambiguous: imagine for example, that Alice is born on January 2, 1990, and today is May 1, 2020. Which of the following is true?

- A. The age range is 18—30 and Alice was born about 30.3 years ago, which is more than 30, hence Alice **is not** a young adult according to the definition above.
- B. The age range is 18—30 and Alice is 30 years old, hence Alice **is** a young adult according to the definition above.

If the definition said "young adults are adults between the ages of 18 and 30", would that change the answer to the above question?

Comment: Thank you, Yosef, for the correction. Fixed.

Comment: If Alice is 30, that fact lasts until she turns 31. Right before her next birthday, she is not yet 31, so a young adult.

Comment: @YosefBaskin With a little more definition, your comment is an answer.

Comment: When somebody asks you how old you are do you say "30" or "30.3"?

Comment: This is not a question about English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is fairly straightforward. The semantics of English (and I imagine most languages, though I do not speak "most" languages) is that you are included as 18-30 from your 18th birthday until the day before your 31st birthday.

Unless one is being pedantic, this is quantized by days. So, for example, if you were born at noon on Jan 1st, 2010, and I asked you how old you were at 11:50am on Jan 1st 2012, you would say 2, even though you were ten minutes short of your actual time of birth. It also completely ignores leap years.[*]

For people who were born on Feb 29th, the rules are a bit fuzzy on non leap years, but usually the person choses either Feb 28th or Mar 1st, to be their effective birthday, and nobody would be so impolite as to argue with them.

Whether than matches your mathematical expectations, that is precisely what it means in English.

[*] It is worth noting that very young people tend to measure their age in smaller units than years. Based on my experience, people younger that 14 days have their age measured in days, people younger than 3 months have their ages measured in weeks, people younger than two years old have their age measured in months, and people younger than ten have their age measured in half years (as in "I am six and a half".) After that we use years. Some older people downshift to decades, but again, who would be so impolite as to challenge them?

Comment: I don't think leap years are ignored per se, it's more that they're irrelevant to everybody not born on Feb 29. If I say it's my 40th birthday today I don't mean that 365 X 40 days have passed since my birth, I mean that 40 years (each of which happens to be either 365 or 366 days) have passed. If my birthday is Feb 29 I can still count my age in years even though that date doesn't occur every year.

Comment: The answer to OP’s question does not change based on which language is being spoken.  it’s therefore off-topic.

Comment: @Jim I don't know if that is true. I only know one other language well, and a couple of others less well, and what you say is true of them, however, I would not be at all surprised if the answer to this were different in languages not within the family of European languages. My limited experience with them is it that is surprising how many assumptions of universality one makes about one's own language.

Comment: Then that means it could be a cultural thing. But not a language thing.

Comment: Notwithstanding the persuasiveness of this argument, if I saw 'aged 18—30', the roundness of 30 would incline me to believe that what was intended was probably something like 'between the 18th and 30th birthday' (why would anybody take the 31st birthday as a cutoff point for anything?). The inclination would be even stronger if the wording were 'the age range is 18—30'. On the other hand, if I saw 'aged 18—29', I would find it natural to interpret it in the way that is argued for in this answer.

Comment: Out of interest Chinese ages are calculated from birth and don't have a "zero years" as English ages do. What an English speaking person calls "a newborn baby" or "a 2 month old baby" is a "one year old" in Chinese terms. In other words Chinese makes no distinction between someone who is thirty years old and someone who is "in their thirtieth year". English speakers usually say that that person is twenty-nine.

Comment: @BoldBen - But to be clear, that’s a cultural thing not a language thing.  In other words that Chinese person (were he bilingual) would not say someone was 30 when speaking Mandarin, but when switching to English say they were 29. Right?

Comment: @Jim i think that would probably depend on how well the Chinese preson knew Englich language and culture. My Chinese was never anything but rudimentary and has declined with lack of use but I think that I would remember to add one year to my European age if I was answering the question. However there will be other parts of Chinese culture that I have forgotton or not learned that would trip me up. The universal solution is to speak in terms of birth dates in Common Era terms.